# Swift 3.0 multiple selection with select all cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

I have added data in table view and I have manually added "select all" option to the list at first position, now when the user selects the first option which is 'select all' then the person manually option "Select all" is not selected. Select all, click then work all person or deselect working but signal selection all the person not working "Select all"
I have tried the code below but it's not working so can any one help me to solve this?

[image]

```
var unchecked:Bool = true
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
            let cell = ObjTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SelectUserCell
            // set the text from the data model
             cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            cell.lblStudentName.text = getStudentName[indexPath.row]

            if UnAll == "unselect" {
                if indexPath.row == 0 {
                    cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "unSelectedItem"), for: .normal)

                }
                if indexPath.row == Int(selectedNumber) {
                    cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "unSelectedItem"), for: .normal)

                }
                if indexPath.row == Int(unSelectNumber) {
                    //var j = "\(i)"

                    cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "selectedItem"), for: .normal)

                }

            }else
            {
            if(unchecked){

                cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "unSelectedItem"), for: .normal)

            }
            else{

                cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "selectedItem"), for: .normal)

              }
            }

            return cell
        }
        var UnAll = ""
        var selectedNumber = ""
        var unSelectNumber = ""
        var checkselect:Bool = true

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            UnAll.removeAll()
            selectedNumber.removeAll()
            unSelectNumber.removeAll()
            if(indexPath.row == 0){

                btnCheckBoxClick(sender: UIButton())

            }else
            {
            UnAll = "unselect"
                btnCheckBoxClick(sender: UIButton())
                if checkselect {
                    selectedNumber = "\(indexPath.row)"
                    checkselect = false
                }else
                {
                  unSelectNumber = "\(indexPath.row)"
                    checkselect = true
                }

                print("the selected index is : \(indexPath.row)")
            }

        }

        @IBAction func btnCheckBoxClick(_ sender: Any) {   

            if(unchecked){

                unchecked = false
            }
            else{              
                unchecked = true
            }
            ObjTableview.reloadData()
         }
```

Comment: @RajeshkumarR yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a struct for model data with a Bool property. You can modify this property by cell selection.

[image: simulator]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  var allCharacters:[Character] = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        allCharacters = [Character(name: "All"),Character(name: "Luke Skywalker"),Character(name: "Leia Organa"),Character(name: "Advik Shah"),Character(name: "Aarav Modi")]

  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allCharacters.count
  }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    if cell == nil{
      cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
      cell?.textLabel?.text = allCharacters[indexPath.row].name
      if allCharacters[indexPath.row].isSelected
      {
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
      }
      else
      {
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
      }
      cell?.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell!
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
      allCharacters[indexPath.row].isSelected = !allCharacters[indexPath.row].isSelected
      for index in allCharacters.indices
      {
        allCharacters[index].isSelected = allCharacters[indexPath.row].isSelected
      }
    }
    else
    {
      allCharacters[indexPath.row].isSelected = !allCharacters[indexPath.row].isSelected
      if allCharacters.dropFirst().filter({ $0.isSelected }).count == allCharacters.dropFirst().count
      {
        allCharacters[0].isSelected = true
      }
      else
      {
        allCharacters[0].isSelected = false
      }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
  }




}

struct Character
{
  var name:String
  //  var otherDetails
  var isSelected:Bool! = false
  init(name:String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}
```

---

### Creating Array of Struct objects from array of dictionary

```
let SubjectArray = json["students"] as! [[String:Any]]
allCharacters = SubjectArray.map({ Character(name: $0["studentName"] as! String) })
allCharacters.insert(Character(name:"All"), at: 0)
```

Comment: @ Rajeshkumar my data come with api through how can be add tableview  like allCharacters

Comment: @ Rajeshkumar R how to add struct in api data

Comment: @ Rajeshkumar R not working error :- Cannot convert call result type '_?' to expected type '[Character]'

Comment: Thanks for discussion

Comment: It saves my time.Thank you @RajeshKumar R

Comment: @Preetha ook :)

Answer (score 4):

I like @Pranil's suggestion of using a separate section for the "All" row, so I have stolen that.

You can use an `NSMutableIndexSet` for tracking the selected rows.  This is simpler than having to create a new struct or array of booleans or something.  The only thing you do need to be aware of is if your tableview allows row reordering then the index set needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Here is my implementation.  The "all" state is determined by the number of selected rows being equal to the number of rows in the data source array.

I have just used simple table view accessories for the checkmarks, but I am sure you can see how to adopt your image based approach in `cellForRow(at:)`

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!


    let names: [String]? = ["Luke Skywalker","Leia Organa","Advik Shah","Aarav Modi"]

    var selectedRows = NSMutableIndexSet()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        guard let names = self.names else {
            return 0
        }

        return 0 == section ? 1 : names.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath)

        var text: String
        var accessory = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none

        if 0 == indexPath.section {
            text = "All"
            if self.selectedRows.count == self.names!.count {
                accessory = .checkmark
            }
        } else {
            text = names![indexPath.row]
            if selectedRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
                accessory = .checkmark
            }
        }

        cell.textLabel!.text = text
        cell.accessoryType = accessory

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            if self.selectedRows.count == self.names!.count {
                self.selectedRows = NSMutableIndexSet()
            } else {
                self.selectedRows = NSMutableIndexSet(indexesIn: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.names!.count))
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath.row) ? self.selectedRows.remove(indexPath.row) : self.selectedRows.add(indexPath.row)

            let rows = [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), indexPath]

            tableView.reloadRows(at: rows, with: .none)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using only one section in the table view. I suggest you use two sections in the table view, so that first section will contain only one row (Select All) and the second section will contain other options. When you click on Select All, that is in the first row of the first section you can make all the rows in the second section as selected while reloading the table view.

```
// MARK: -  struct for cell item
    struct CellItem {
    var name : String
    var isSelected:Bool! = false
    init(name: String) {
           self.name = name
         }
    }

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet var viewTable: UITableView!
// Declare a boolean varaible to toggle the checkbox in the first section of table view
var isSelectAllSelected : Bool = false
var cellData: [CellItem] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cellData = [CellItem(name: "Luke Skywalker"),CellItem(name: "Leia Organa"),CellItem(name: "Advik Shah"),CellItem(name: "Aarav Modi")]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
         return 1
    }
    else
    {
        return cellData.count
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

// MARK: -  Table view delegates

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = TableCell()
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Select All"
        if isSelectAllSelected{
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = cellData[indexPath.row].name
        if cellData[indexPath.row].isSelected{
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

    }
    return cell
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        cellData[indexPath.row].isSelected = !cellData[indexPath.row].isSelected
        isSelectAllSelected = cellData[indexPath.row].isSelected
        for index in cellData.indices
        {
            cellData[index].isSelected = cellData[indexPath.row].isSelected
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cellData[indexPath.row].isSelected = !cellData[indexPath.row].isSelected
        if cellData.filter({ $0.isSelected }).count == cellData.count
        {
            isSelectAllSelected = true
        }
        else
        {
            isSelectAllSelected = false
        }

    }
    viewTable.reloadData()
} }
```

Comment: @ pranil any example ..?

Comment: @JayprakashSingh I have edited my answer to include table view data sources and delegates to implement the logic using table view sections.

Comment: Guys, please refer the GitHub link in which I have shown how exactly we can use  table view sections to implement multiple selections  with a select all cell: https://github.com/ipran/TableView-MultipleSelection

Answer (score 2):

Hello u can take cheboxbutton action method inside view controller with addtarget method and assign tag indexpath.row so u can easily get the indexpath. from below code u can get the idea.

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var ObjTableview: UITableView!
var arrStudent = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
var arrSelectedStudent :[Int] = []
var selectAll:Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//MARK: UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrStudent.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let cell = ObjTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! SelectUserCell
    // set the text from the data model
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
   // cell.lblStudentName.text = getStudentName[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblStudentName.text = arrStudent[indexPath.row]
    cell.btnCheckbox.tag = indexPath.row
   cell.btnCheckbox.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnCheckBoxClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)


    if selectAll {
        cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "selectedItem"), for: .normal)
    }else{
    if arrSelectedStudent.contains(indexPath.row){
        cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "selectedItem"), for: .normal)
    }else{
        cell.btnCheckbox.setImage(UIImage(named: "unSelectedItem"), for: .normal)
    }
    }

         return cell
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 }

func btnCheckBoxClick(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 0{
        selectAll = true
    }else
    {
        selectAll = false
    if let index = arrSelectedStudent.index(of: sender.tag) {
        arrSelectedStudent.remove(at: index)
    }else{
        arrSelectedStudent.append(sender.tag)
    }
    }

    ObjTableview.reloadData()
}}
```