# iOS- How to keep a default switch on and turn it off when any other switch is pressed

Tags: ios, swift

Using `UITableView`s I made a filter table. Image attached. "All" is the default On switch.
I have attached a selector function to the switches that identify with tags.
[image: Filter Table]

How can one make it so that if any other switch is pressed, state of the All switch should change?

I am a newbie. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440026/swift-3-0-multiple-selection-with-select-all-cell/46442507#46442507) for an approach that could work for you; you will need to adopt a delegate pattern to get the switch on/off events into your tableview rather than using `willSelectRowAt` as I did in that answer.

Comment: Are these dynamic cells or static cells?

Comment: @MacLean Dynamic cells mate.

Comment: @Paulw11seems correct, you can post it here and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @TheDoctor It's should be a `static cell`. And then you can do anything like that.