# how to select Table View row selection with custom checkbox button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to select tableview row with custom button . i have another button called select all its outside of the table view my question is while clicking outside of the tableview button how to select and deselect inside tableview rows? At the same time i could able to select single row in the tableview ? how to do it in swift 3? This is my code in cellforrow method

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let identifier = "Custom"
    var cell: TStudentAttendanceCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? TStudentAttendanceCell
    if cell == nil {
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TStudentAttendanceCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? TStudentAttendanceCell
    }
    print("studentAttendanvceArray--",studentAttendanceArray.object(at: indexPath.row) )
    var localDic :NSDictionary!

    localDic = studentAttendanceArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary

    Common.sharedInstance.StopActivity()        
    cell.profile_img.image = self.image
    cell.name_lbl.text = localDic["student_name"] as? String
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 8, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 90))

    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.9])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView)
    cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: whiteRoundedView)

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear provide relevant code

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440026/swift-3-0-multiple-selection-with-select-all-cell/46440780#46440780

Comment: I have seen that code but here my all button is outside of the tableview .

Comment: @kishan I didn't see any button in cellforrow method. Do you have any?

Comment: @rajesh i havent written anything i am not getting anything how to do that thatswhy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
  var allStudentsArr:[[String:String]] = []
  var selectedRows:[IndexPath] = []


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
    allStudentsArr = [["name":"name1"],["name":"name2"],["name":"name3"],["name":"name4"],["name":"name5"],["name":"name6"],["name":"name7"],["name":"name8"]]
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return allStudentsArr.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.nameLbl.text = allStudentsArr[indexPath.row]["name"]
    if selectedRows.contains(indexPath)
    {
      cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"selected"), for: .normal)
    }
    else
    {
      cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"unselected"), for: .normal)
    }
    cell.checkBox.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBoxSelection(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
  }
  @objc func checkBoxSelection(_ sender:UIButton)
  {
    let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    if self.selectedRows.contains(selectedIndexPath)
    {
      self.selectedRows.remove(at: self.selectedRows.index(of: selectedIndexPath)!)
    }
    else
    {
      self.selectedRows.append(selectedIndexPath)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
  @IBAction func selectAllBtnAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.selectedRows = getAllIndexPaths()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }

  func getAllIndexPaths() -> [IndexPath] {
    var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
      for j in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: j, section: 0))
      }
        return indexPaths
  }
}
```

**Custom Cell**

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet var nameLbl: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var checkBox: UIButton!
}
```

Comment: i used this,it is working fine..And am having doubt regarding this selection,In my case need to getting selected cell's data but am receiving the last object's data,But the index will different for each objects.Can you please help me get that value.

Comment: Yes i need to figure that solution for that,if you can please help me.

Comment: Can you explain your prob?

Comment: Problem is selected cell's data will be repeated...For ex: Consider [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] in this array your selected 2,4,8,9 and the index (1,3,7,8) of the selected objects returns correct only..but the cell's data is returns like (9,9,9,9) last object and the count will be number of selected objects.This is the problem am facing.

Comment: "but the cell's data is returns like (9,9,9,9) " How do you get the cell's data?

Comment: In the Checkbox selection method i have to create cell and get the value.

Comment: NO. Don't create cell outside cellfor row method.

Comment: Ok fine.How i need to get selected cell's data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169637/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-preetha).

Comment: Thank you @RajeshKumar for helping me to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how you can programatically select all rows of a single section

```
@IBAction func didTapSelectAllButton(sender: UIButton) {
        let totalRows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)// Make some logic if you have more than 1 section
        for row in 0..<totalRows {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
            tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to use default check box of `tableView` then disable multipleSelection from `tableView` and implement logic using an extra global array.

```
var selectedArrayIndex = [Int]()
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedArrayIndex.contains(indexPath.row) {
        selectedArrayIndex.remove(at: selectedArrayIndex.index(of: indexPath.row)!)
    }else {
        selectedArrayIndex.append(indexPath.row)
    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if selectedArrayIndex.contains(indexPath.row) {
        // Enable You Check
        cell.checkBoxView.isHidden = false
    }else {
        cell.checkBoxView.isHidden = true
    }
}
@IBAction func didTapSelectAllButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let totalRows = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)// Make some logic if you have more than 1 section
    selectedArrayIndex.removeAll()
    for row in 0..<totalRows {
        selectedArrayIndex.append(row)
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i have taken xib file for tableview cell. in that i have taken one button for checkmark . so when ever i click on all button or when ever i click on single row state should be change . and button image also should be changed to slected state.

Comment: You need an other array in which you will add your selected data. And remove it when you deselect them. Then in cellForRow method you will check if data at this index is present in selected array if yes then mark select else un selected.

Comment: can you give sample code i am not cleared about your solution @Syed Qamar.

Comment: @kishan check it now.

Comment: i used this code and am facing one issue,which is i have to send the selected to the API,and the last index object will be empty.Why it is happening?

Comment: Are you facing empty data in last Object of selected array?

Comment: Or you need to set the last Object empty?