# Swift tableview cell select to change checkbox image

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to implement custom button check box in tableview cell. I have done checkbox when user clicks cell button it can change check and uncheck but if you click tableview cell also I needs to operate the check box

If possible please give some idea for radio button functionality because I am doing both.

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell

        cell.myCellLabel.text = self.animals[indexPath.row]

        if selectedRows.contains(indexPath)
        {
            cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        cell.checkBox.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBoxSelection(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    // method to run when table view cell is tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    }

    @objc func checkBoxSelection(_ sender:UIButton)
    {
        let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        if self.selectedRows.contains(selectedIndexPath)
        {
            self.selectedRows.remove(at: self.selectedRows.index(of: selectedIndexPath)!)
        }
        else
        {
            self.selectedRows.append(selectedIndexPath)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the **selected cell** in `didSelectRowAt` delegate and set the checkmark.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell else {
        return
    }
    if self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
        self.selectedRows.remove(at: self.selectedRows.index(of: indexPath)!)
        cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"unccheck.png"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        self.selectedRows.append(indexPath)
        cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow Great help @Rakesha Shastri. Btw how to do radio button functionality ?

Comment: @iosdev there are plenty of those in stack overflow already, you could find them easily. If they do not however meet your requirement, you could put up another question, specifying your exact use case and people would help you out. ;)

Comment: Thank you lot buddy. I will try. Now I placed my cell button click to get cell label value but getting one error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Comment: @iosdev again i'm reiterating you should refrain from asking **new** question as a comment. They should always be posted separately. And this error is a very popular error whose solution is all over stackoverflow. Ask a new question supplying the necessary code and mark the line which gives your the error. but first try searching if it has already been asked and answered.

Comment: It would a cleaner approach to just update the data model (selectedRows) and then reload the row at `indexPath`. It avoids duplicating lots of code between `cellForRowAt` and `didSelectRowAt`.

Comment: @rmaddy point noted. I’ll update the answer as soon as i can.

Answer (score 0):

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300399/how-to-select-table-view-row-selection-with-custom-checkbox-button

import UIKit

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var checkBox: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var myCellLabel: UILabel!
}

class UpdateViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // These strings will be the data for the table view cells
    var animals: [String] = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]
    var selectedRows:[IndexPath] = []

    // These are the colors of the square views in our table view cells.
    // In a real project you might use UIImages.
    let colors = [UIColor.blue, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.magenta, UIColor.red, UIColor.brown]

    // Don't forget to enter this in IB also
    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Remove unused array
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        //tableView.allowsSelection = false

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    // number of rows in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.animals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:MyCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as! MyCustomCell

        cell.myCellLabel.text = self.animals[indexPath.row]

        if selectedRows.contains(indexPath)
        {
            cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        cell.checkBox.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBoxSelection(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    // method to run when table view cell is tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")

        guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell else {
            return
        }
        if self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath) {
            self.selectedRows.remove(at: self.selectedRows.index(of: indexPath)!)
            cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"uncheck.png"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            self.selectedRows.append(indexPath)
            cell.checkBox.setImage(UIImage(named:"check.png"), for: .normal)

            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow //optional, to get from any UIButton for example
            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! MyCustomCell
            print(currentCell.myCellLabel.text ?? "")
        }
    }

    @objc func checkBoxSelection(_ sender:UIButton)
    {
        let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        if self.selectedRows.contains(selectedIndexPath)
        {
            self.selectedRows.remove(at: self.selectedRows.index(of: selectedIndexPath)!)
        }
        else
        {
            self.selectedRows.append(selectedIndexPath)

            let center = sender.center
            let point = sender.superview!.convert(center, to:self.tableView)
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)
            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! MyCustomCell //Add superview on the basis of your button hierarchy in the cell
            let cell_labelvalue =  cell.myCellLabel!.text
            print(cell_labelvalue ?? "")

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func selectAllBtnAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.selectedRows = getAllIndexPaths()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func getAllIndexPaths() -> [IndexPath] {
        var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
        for j in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: j, section: 0))
        }
        return indexPaths
    }


    @IBAction func cancelPopup(_ sender: Any) {
        self.removeAnimate()
    }

    @IBAction func donePopUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        self.removeAnimate()
    }

    func showAnimate()
    {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 1.0
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        });
    }

    func removeAnimate()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            self.view.alpha = 0.0;
        }, completion:{(finished : Bool)  in
            if (finished)
            {
                self.view.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this code? Is this some sort of answer to your question? Is this a new question? Don't just post code with no explanation.