# Best way to select multiple items in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, picker

I'm writing an iOS app in Swift. I want to display a bunch of items (team names) and want the user to select many of them for a league. What's the best way to do this? I could use a picker view, and take each one out as they are selected. I would like to use checkboxes, but there is nothing built in for that. Maybe a table view with multiple checking? Has anyone already done this and have a good method to use?

Comment: Use tableview and enable multiple selection. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46440780/7250862

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into using a tableview. This is good because I haven't used one before.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best/easiest way to do it is with a UITableView and all you have to do is enable multiple cell selection. Then you can retrieve them by using

```
table.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```