# Issue with multiple selection and select all in UITableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, multipleselection, selectall

In my application I have an multiple selection and select all option, I've tried by used below code but am facing an issue with selection.

If I press selectAll it checks and unchecks clearly and If suppose, I choose an single selection it selected but the selected cell is not higlighted.

Can you any one help me to figure out.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return self.array.count
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath ,

```
let cell = self.multipleSelectionTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:multiSelectionIdentifier , for: indexPath) as! MultipleSelectionCell
        if self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath){
            cell.checkBoxBtn.isSelected = true
            cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "check"), for: .normal)

        } else {
            cell.checkBoxBtn.isSelected = false
            cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
        }


        if self.multipleSelectionStatusBtn.isSelected == true {
            self.multipleSelectionStatusBtn.isSelected = true
            cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "check"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            self.multipleSelectionStatusBtn.isSelected = false
            cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
        }

        cell.checkBoxBtn.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
```

In checkbox selection method,

```
let selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        self.multipleSelectionTableview.deselectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: true)
        if self.selectedRows.contains(selectedIndexPath)
        {

            self.selectedRows.remove(at: self.selectedRows.index(of: selectedIndexPath)!)
        }
        else
        {

            self.selectedRows.append(selectedIndexPath)
            print(self.selectedRows)

        }

        self.multipleSelectionTableview.reloadData()
```

In selectAll method,

```
if (sender.isSelected == true)
        {

            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
            sender.isSelected = false;
           // isSelecting = false
            self.selectedRows = self.getAllIndexpaths()
            self.multipleSelectionTableview.reloadData()

        }
        else
        {
           // isSelecting = true
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
            sender.isSelected = true;
            self.selectedRows = self.getAllIndexpaths()
            self.multipleSelectionTableview.reloadData()
        }
```

For getAllIndexPaths Method,

```
func getAllIndexpaths() -> [IndexPath] {
        var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
        for j in 0..<self.multipleSelectionTableview.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) {
            indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: j, section: 0))
        }
        return indexPaths
    }
```

Comment: you can implement `willSelectRowAt:` of tableview delegate method and change cell background colour,

Comment: check your cellForRowAtIndexPath once, you validate the multiple condition

Comment: make sure you have set tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

Comment: @Anbu.karthik after the single selection that cell is not called but the selected status will be append in selected row's array.

Comment: @HAK already enabled multiple selection status.

Comment: @MahendraGP how can i implement..Can you please give me some piece of code / samples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46440780/7250862 Check this

Answer (score 1):

You have to store selected index path in Array Like this Way you can do this easily.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var selectedRow:[IndexPath] = []
@IBOutlet var tblView:UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:
    Int) -> Int
{
    return 100
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = String(format:"%@",indexPath.row)

    if selectedRow.contains(indexPath)
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else
    {
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
    }        
    return cell!
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if selectedRow.contains(indexPath)
    {
        // For  Remove Row selection
        selectedRow.remove(at: selectedRow.index(of: indexPath)!)
    }
    else
    {
        selectedRow.append(indexPath)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

// Call this method for Select All
func selectAllCall()
{
    var indexPaths: [IndexPath] = []
    for j in 0..<100
    {
        indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: j, section: 0))
    }

    selectedRow.removeAll()

    selectedRow.append(contentsOf: indexPaths)

    tblView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are reloading data when check box is checked or unchecked. That's the reason the table view doesn't keep the selection.

Solution.

You need to keep track of the selected index paths. And in `cellForRowAt:` you need to check that if it is the checked index path the you need to make cell highlight by changing its background colour otherwise set cell background colour white or something else.

For eg.

```
//In cellForRowAtIndexPath

 if arrSelectedIndexPath.contains(indexPath) {
     // checkbox is checked, change cell bg color
 } else {
    // checkbox is not checked
 }
```

`arrSelectedIndexPath` is an `[IndexPath]` an array of index paths. When check box is selected you need to insert index path in an array and when check box is unchecked then you need to delete that index path from an array.

Comment: var selectedRows : [IndexPath] = [], i used like this only

Comment: you can check whether `selectedRows` contains the selected index path contains or not and based on that you can highlight cell.

Comment: After the single selection the cellForRowAtIndexpath is not called.In mulitple selction it is called,

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with your logic implementation in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`:

First you are checking if `selectedRows` array contains selected `index path` or not and setting the UI of `checkBoxBtn`:

```
let cell = self.multipleSelectionTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:multiSelectionIdentifier , for: indexPath) as! MultipleSelectionCell
if self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath){
    cell.checkBoxBtn.isSelected = true
    cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "check"), for: .normal)

} else {
    cell.checkBoxBtn.isSelected = false
    cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "uncheck[enter image description here][1]"), for: .normal)
}
```

Then again you are checking for `multipleSelectionStatusBtn` and changing the UI of `checkBoxBtn` :

```
if self.multipleSelectionStatusBtn.isSelected == true {
    self.multipleSelectionStatusBtn.isSelected = true
    cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "check_timesheet"), for: .normal)
} else {
    self.multipleSelectionStatusBtn.isSelected = false
    cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "uncheck_timesheet"), for: .normal)
}

cell.checkBoxBtn.tag = indexPath.row
return cell
```

When `tableView` will reload obviously this will work in multiple selection and not in single selection.

**Change**

In `selectAll` method :

```
if (sender.isSelected == true)
{

    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
    sender.isSelected = false;
   // isSelecting = false
    self.selectedRows.removeAll()
    self.multipleSelectionTableview.reloadData()

}
else
{
   // isSelecting = true
    sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
    sender.isSelected = true;
    self.selectedRows = self.getAllIndexpaths()
    self.multipleSelectionTableview.reloadData()
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
let cell = self.multipleSelectionTableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:multiSelectionIdentifier , for: indexPath) as! MultipleSelectionCell
if self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath){
    cell.checkBoxBtn.isSelected = true
    cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "check"), for: .normal)

} else {
    cell.checkBoxBtn.isSelected = false
    cell.checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "uncheck[enter image description here][1]"), for: .normal)
}
if getTimeSheetJSON[indexPath.row]["TaskName"].string == "" {
    cell.checkBoxBtn.isHidden = true
} else {
    cell.checkBoxBtn.isHidden = false
}

cell.checkBoxBtn.tag = indexPath.row
return cell
```

Hope this works as I haven't compiled your code in `Xcode`.

Comment: Changed the "In selectAll method" logic. Please check now.

Comment: That you are already saving in `selectedRows array` right...??